# Proof that $n$ planes cut a solid torus into a maximum of $\frac16(n^3+3n^2+8n)$ pieces

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, puzzle, visualization

**Question:** How many pieces can a solid torus be cut into with three (affine) planar cuts?

A google search will quickly reveal that the answer is thirteen, as can be read about [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/slicing-a-donut-3-ways-whats-the-most-number-of-pieces). The picture below displays this solution. However, despite being able to look at the diagram and confirm that thirteen pieces is indeed possible, I do not see how one would prove this is the *maximum* number of cuts. Furthermore, I have found the following general formula for $n$ cuts: $f(n)=\frac{1}{6}(n^3+3n^2+8n)$, but have not been able to find a proof for this either.

**Better Question:** How does one prove that thirteen is the maximum number of pieces with three cuts, and that $f$ provides the number of pieces with $n$ cuts?

[image]

Comment: Not answering the question, but more info: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TorusCutting.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an intuitive, heuristic argument that I think makes it clear why the formula has to work [plausibly this could be made rigorous although the details are more elusive than I thought at first]: The maximum number of pieces is not going to change if you change the relative size of the donut and the hole, or if you stretch the donut in one direction. So you can think of a fat, sort of cigar-shaped, donut with a very skinny long hole in it. In fact, taking this equivalence to its logical extreme, you'll get the same number of pieces if your donut is just a cake with a slit cut through the middle of it (the slit does not touch any side of the cake, so from above it looks like $\Theta$ -- notice how the crossbar does not actually touch the outer circle).

Now, instead of starting with a slitted cake, we can think of cutting a cake with $n$ planar cuts, and then cutting the slit. But the slit is just like an $(n+1)$st planar cut, except that because it doesn't reach the edges of the cake, there must be (at least) two pieces of cake that it doesn't manage to separate. Therefore, the maximum slitted cake/torus number of pieces with $n$ cuts is just the maximum number of pieces you can cut a cake into with $n+1$ cuts, minus two. But the cake numbers $C(n)$ are already well known; see https://oeis.org/A000125 for a proof that $C(n) = (n^3+5n+6)/6$.

Finally, substituting gives us the torus formula $f(n) = C(n+1) - 2 = ((n+1)^3+5(n+1)+6-12)/6 = (n^3+3n^2+8n)/6$, as expected.

Comment: Glen says “The maximum number of pieces is not going to change if you change the relative size of the donut and the hole, or if you stretch the donut in one direction.” That seems credible, but how does one prove it? (The group of invertible maps of 3-space that preserves planes isn’t big enough to do the job.) Is there really no published literature on this problem?

Comment: Clearly given a "thin" donut cut into $n$ pieces by $c$ cuts, you can add arbitrarily more material away from the center hole without reducing the number of pieces, since any two pieces which are on the same sides of all $c$ planes are on opposite sides of the hole. So the maximum won't decrease by making the donut "fatter" relative to the hole. That's enough for this heuristic (the trickier "thinning" direction is needed to see that the maximum number of pieces is the same for any torus which is a solid of revolution of a circle). The "stretching in one direction" does preserve planes.

Comment: But I now realize the trickier bit to make rigorous is given a dissection of a donut into $n$ pieces by $c$ cuts, you can find a single plane which separates all pairs of pieces of the donut that are on the same sides of all $c$ of the planes. I don't have an easy argument for this step, and so consequently I have removed the definitive "can be made rigorous" from my answer (my apologies for being overconfident before). Nevertheless, I do feel this heuristic illuminates why the formula has to be the correct one (assuming there is such a formula in the first place).