# Doughnut Slicing Problem

Tags: geometry, reference-request

Here:
[Proof that $n$ planes cut a solid torus into a maximum of $\frac16(n^3+3n^2+8n)$ pieces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146697/proof-that-n-planes-cut-a-solid-torus-into-a-maximum-of-frac16n33n28n)
an intuitive idea of understanding the formula of Torus Slicing is given. Nevertheless I wanted to ask if there is any concrete Literature with a formal proof given?

In this book:

Gardner, M. Mathematical Magic Show: More Puzzles, Games, Diversions, Illusions and Other Mathematical Sleight-of-Mind from Scientific American New York: Vintage, 1978.

Gardner writes in Chapter 13:

> *Many interesting letters about the doughnut-slicing problem were received. Derrill Bordelon, of the U.S. Naval Ordnance Laboratory at Silver Spring, Maryland, sent a detailed
> proof of the formula for $n$ cuts.*

Has anyone an idea if there is a published formal proof or a book containing one?

Comment: 10th edition of this question. I wish OP would stop making tiny edits to bring this question back to the front page.

Comment: There is something like a proof at https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1khxz7/slicing_a_torus/

Comment: @GerryMyerson I thought about finding the Cake Number proof and adapting it. Maybe I'll post it here some day.